# What is the best way to display multiple ImageViews in a fragment?

Tags: android

The images in my fragment are slow to show? or load?

I have a constraint layout that displays up to about 40 various ImageViews. All videos are shown simultaneously. When I navigate to the fragment it can take up to a second or two for the navigation to end.

The images are in my project as drawables and programmatically found by their drawable id and displayed programmatically, not in a list.

How can I do this better for a better experience?

Comment: I think you can use `RecyclerView` to display the list image because user can not see all image at the same time

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Thank you, all images are shown at the same time. They are part of the fragment's layout.

Comment: what @PhanVanLinh meant is at any instance of time, the user will be just looking at 5-10 images and not all 40, so try using a `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Sekiro Yes, that is what I understood. This is a tablet only app. I am saying that all 40 images are displayed and visible at all times for this fragment. Only seeing 5 - 10 images would not allow it to function as each image links to a different area.

Answer (score 0):

While using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` would make your life really easy, If you are really not willing then here's a few suggestions:

I am assuming by referring to time taken for navigation you are saying that the actual transition from a fragment/activity to this particular fragment happens really slowly. So for most of the time you are staring at a blank screen.

i) first, place some blank placeholder images to your `ImageViews`. So that the user at least knows that the app hasn't stopped responding.

ii) secondly, if you are using any of the `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()` methods to initialize your `ImageView`s programmatically, I suggest you move this code to `onStart()` method of your fragment.

iii) lastly, use `Glide` library to asynchronously load your `ImageView`s with the images.